# Using the ALL operator in linq to filter child items of EntitySet

Tags: linq

I have a two objects as follows:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId {get;set;}
    public string ItemName {get;set;}
    public List<Tag> ItemTags {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId {get;set;}
    public string TagName {get;set;}
}
```

These are LINQ-to-SQL objects, so the ItemTags will be an EntitySet.

I am trying to perform a search query where a user can provide a comma delimited list of tags as a search filter.

How do I filter my list of items to those which contains all of the tags in the comma delimited list.

EDIT2

```
e.g.
Item1 has tags of Apple, Banana, Orange
Item2 has tags of Banana, Orange
Item3 has tags of Pineapple, Orange
If the tag filter is "Banana, Orange" I need the results to be Item1 and Item2.
```

/EDIT2

This is what I have tried thus far:

```
string tags = "Manchester United,European Cup,2008";
List<string> tagsList = tags.Trim().ToLower()
    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToList();

List<Item> itemList = ItemRepository.FetchAll();

var query = itemList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateCreated)
    .ToList();

if (tagsList.Count() > 0)
{
    query = query
        .Where(p => p.ItemTags
            .Select(q => q.TagName.ToLower())
            .All(r => tagsList.Contains(r)))
        .ToList();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong please?

EDIT1: tags are trimmed and are 'lowercased'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because you're puting the tags from the items to lowercase, but not the searched tags.

With this modification it should work:

```
List<string> tagsList = tags
    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.ToLower())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

---

EDIT: OK, I see what the problem is: you're doing it backwards. You're searching for items that have *only* the tags that you're looking for.

Try that instead:

```
query = 
    (from item in query
     let itemTags = p.ItemTags.Select(it => it.TagName.ToLower())
     where tags.All(t => itemTags.Contains(t))
     select item).ToList();
```

---

UPDATE: here's a version with the lambda syntax. It's pretty ugly because of the temporary anonymous type, but that's how the `let` clause translates to lambda...

```
query =
    query.Select(item => new { item, itemTags = item.ItemTags.Select(it => it.TagName.ToLower()) })
         .Where(x => tagsList.All(t => x.itemTags.Contains(t)))
         .Select(x => x.item)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I tried that as well, I've updated the main question.

Comment: Hi Thomas, the compiler gives me a compile error when I tried your code at the final parentheses before the .ToList() call. The error is "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause". Any ideas - sorry I only know how to use linq-to-sql with lambda notation :)

Comment: I forgot the select clause... it's fixed now

Comment: Ah brilliant this worked like a charm. I had to change a couple of typos:
    (from item in query
     let itemTags = item.ItemTags.Select(it => it.TagName.ToLower())
     where tagsList.All(t => itemTags.Contains(t))
     select item).ToList();

Comment: As a final question, you wouldn't happen to know how to write this as a lambda expression instead of a linq query? :-)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept if it solves your problem ;). Translating the `let` clause to lambda syntax is a real pain, that's why I used the query syntax... I'll try to post a lambda version. Anyway, why don't you want the query syntax ? In some cases it's more convenient than the lambda syntax, and it's not more difficult to use (actually it's probably easier...)

Comment: OK, I added the lambda syntax version

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
var query = itemList.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateCreated).ToList();

var results = query.Where(i => i.ItemTags
   .All(it => tagsList.Contains(it.TagName.ToLower())));
```

Then `results` should then be a list of matching items.

PS. Your code shows you fetching `itemList` as a List from your repository and *then* sorting by date created. This means the sorting isn't being done in the database. Once you turn something into a List you give up the benefits of deferred execution as you will bring back the entire collection into memory.

EDIT: Here's the test code to prove it works in Linq to Objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> ItemTags { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTags();
    }

    private static void RunTags()
    {
        Item i1 = new Item()
        {
            ItemId = 1,
            ItemName = "Item1",
            ItemTags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { TagId = 1, TagName = "2008" }, new Tag { TagId = 2, TagName = "Donkey" } }
        };

        Item i2 = new Item()
        {
            ItemId = 2,
            ItemName = "Item2",
            ItemTags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { TagId = 4, TagName = "Cat" }, new Tag { TagId = 2, TagName = "Donkey" }, new Tag { TagId = 3, TagName = "Seattle" } }
        };

        Item i3 = new Item()
        {
            ItemId = 3,
            ItemName = "Item3",
            ItemTags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { TagId = 523, TagName = "Manchester united" }, new Tag { TagId = 10, TagName = "European Cup" }, new Tag { TagId = 1, TagName = "2008" } }
        };

        Item i4 = new Item()
        {
            ItemId = 4,
            ItemName = "Item4",
            ItemTags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { TagId = 05, TagName = "Banana" }, new Tag { TagId = 140, TagName = "Foo" }, new Tag { TagId = 4, TagName = "Cat" } }
        };

        Item i5 = new Item()
        {
            ItemId = 5,
            ItemName = "Item5",
            ItemTags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { TagId = 05, TagName = "Banana" }, new Tag { TagId = 140, TagName = "Foo" } }
        };

        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>() { i1, i2, i3, i4, i5 };

        string tags = "Manchester United,European Cup,2008";
        List<string> tagsList = tags.Trim().ToLower()
            .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            .ToList();

        var query = itemList
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateCreated).ToList();


        var results = query.Where(i => i.ItemTags.All(it => tagsList.Contains(it.TagName.ToLower())));

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ItemName); // Should return "Item3"
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If you want to match any of the tags in the Item's ItemTag list then just change All to Any i.e.

```
var results = query.Where(i => i.ItemTags.Any(it => tagsList.Contains(it.TagName.ToLower())));
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I've tried your code and that doesn't work too unfortunately :( What is really strange is that the records returned by the query return only Items with empty ItemTags. The other strange thing I noticed is that if I replace the All operator with Any, the Any statement return results that I would expect from it (returns records which contains 1 or more of the tags). Now I just need to get this 'All' to work.. grr :(

Comment: It definitely works in Linq to Objects - see example code I've added to the answer. Maybe it doesn't translate to Linq to Entities as SQL? Or maybe your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Hi Dan, if you try changing the value of: string tags = "Banana"; Will your results still work? I would require it to return items 4 and 5.

Comment: @Astrofaes You said in your original statement that, "How do I filter my list of items to only those which contains ALL of the tags in the comma delimited list?" Therefore if you changed string tags to "Banana" it wouldn't match 4 and 5 since it is not matching ALL tags, as per your statement.

Comment: I apologise, I should have been more specific in my OP. Any ideas on how to filter based on the revised condition?

Comment: Just change the All to Any - I'll edit my response to show alternative.