# Querying MVC collection with Array

Tags: linq, frameworks, entity

Im using entity framework 4 and linq/lamda expressions. Im sure its an easy one but im trying to query a collection with an array but get records which contain all the arrays values.

basically what im doing is this

```
var records = collection.where(x.classifications.Any(y=> Array.Contains(y.ClassificationID))).ToList()
```

This works in a sense that it returns records that contain any of the arrays values but how do i get only records that contain all of the values in the array.

Hope that makes sense

EDIT:

Im marking the comment below as the answer as I did have to use ALL in my query to get it to work, however I also had to re - write my query slightly. This is what i eventually had...

```
  var records = collection.Where(x=> Array.All(c=> x.Classifications.Select(l=>l.ClassificationID).Contains(c)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `All` instead of `Any`?

```
var records = collection.Where(x => x.classifications.All(y => Array.Contains(y.ClassificationID)))
                        .ToList()
```

Comment: I have tried using All but this returns only records that have 0 Classifications, odd. I think my problem looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524466/using-the-all-operator-in-linq-to-filter-child-items-of-entityset

Comment: @JamesBurton then why are you sure that you have items, where all classification contained in array? Maybe some of ClassificationIDs is not in your array

Comment: at the moment im controlling what classids are passed through as i know what records have what ids in my test data. Im only passing through 2 values in my array at the moment to makesure its working. That still doesnt explain why All returns only items that have 0 classifications

Comment: @JamesBurton completely explains. If item do not have classifications, than all its classifications in array

Comment: @JamesBurton thanks for accepting, sorry for misunderstanding your intent